# Does any button in a form automatically submit? How do I disable this?

Tags: html

I'm trying to have a clear button inside a html form, but it appears to automatically submit.  How do I work around this?

I feel like I am missing something obvious.

Thank you, I have a working answer ... so now I'm just curious.  Is there any reason to use the button element in a form, or any reason not to?

Comment: It's usually useful if you post some snippet of code to be able to show anyone interested in helping you out exactly where you are going wrong

Comment: yea, it really is something obvious :)

Comment: The main reason to use the button element is that it can contain arbitrary markup; just make sure you specify the type attribute appropriately. For example, the following can only be achieved with <button>:

<button type="button">
<p><img src="rabbit.png" alt="rabbit"></p>
<p>This button has a picture of a rabbit, and <b>bold text</b> on part of it's contents.</p>
<p>It also contains multiple paragraphs.</p>
</button>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to make the type of the input element "`reset`", not "`submit`".

edit: fixed .. reset, not clear

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset Form">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, instead of submit button :

```
<input type="reset" value="Clear Form">
```